# Using RestSharp with Xamarin - Execute() throws exceptions when HTTP request fails

Tags: c#, exception, xamarin, restsharp

I'm using the RestSharp 105.2.3.0 in my project which runs on Xamarin.Android 6.0.1.10.

Everything was ok, but couple of days the call to Execute() method started throwing exceptions if HTTP requests did not succeed (I guess it's related to the update of the Xamarin platform?).

For example, I receive "System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden." for the 403 response status code and "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No route to host" if the host is unreachable.

This is weird, since on this page - https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Recommended-Usage - I see:

> Note that exceptions from Execute are not thrown but are available in the ErrorException property.

Also, I found a [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32824075/restsharp-how-to-handle-non-200-responses-restclient-throws-exception-on-exec) which is more or less for the same issue.

The proposed solution is to set the IgnoreResponseStatusCode property:

```
var client = new RestClient();
client.IgnoreResponseStatusCode = true;
```

But I don't see this property among those available in RestClient.

How could I fix this? Of course, I can wrap the Execute call in try..catch, but I would prefer to avoid it since the Execute is not supposed to throw exceptions in the first place.

Comment: if the behavior is not in line with the documentation, I'd file a bug with the RestSharp team

Comment: I created an issue on GitHub to see if maybe there are reasons for such behavior - https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/822

Comment: @bene11i, i'm trying to install RestSharp in my PCL project and i'm not getting. Can you help me how to install in the xamarin.forms? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out.

The problem was related to the fact that in the Exception settings window (Debug -> Exceptions...) in Visual Studio all checkboxes were checked in the "Break when an exception is: Thrown" column.

So the exception was caught by the RestSharp code, but VS was still breaking the execution at the Execute call as it was configured to do so.

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0Fc4.png